# How to see all files shared to a specific user Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-search

Context: You want to find all the files/folders that you have access to or are part of your organization which are shared to a specific user.

This is an important ability to security if you need to revoke access to a user who is not part of your organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Google Drive search bar write

```
to:usanername@example.com
```

where `usanername@example.com` is the email address of the user that want to see the files shared with them and that you have access too.